# Automate APK testing

Tags: android, testing, automation, apk

I generally get an Android app to test. Let's say, an app which take two inputs and generate an output based on some algo. I want to automate the testing, where I can provide around 100 different sets of input and print the result may be in form of logs. I don't get the code of application from Dev team, just the APK to install. Please suggest best way to automate the testing. I'm familiar with Java.

Answer (score 0):

No need to get the code form dev team to do this automation, follow these steps.

1. First store 100 input items in a file those you want to punt in input field
2. Now Create a function which can send input data in input field and produce output
3. First get the locator of the input field where you can give input and send the data with the help of sendkeys function used in selenium.
4. As you send the key in input filed , output produces and get the text of that output and print this output in console.

Example:-
for(1 to 100){
  get input data from file index vise
  send this input data in input field 
  receive output from output field
  print this output on console
}